# Error accessing Custom WebService

Tags: 2007, web-services

We have some applications in Sharepoint that rely on Custom Webservices.
The asmx are hosted on a specific path inside the webapplication (and not on the contentdb), and the websites were toplevel, so they worked like charm. Example url:

http://svsp1:2201/webservices/ws.asmx

But we have a new application here that is not a top-level one, and we're not succeding in using it like that.

1. It gives the following error: "The file you are attempting to save or retrieve has been blocked from this Web site by the server administrators."
2. When I disable the limitation for ASMX on Central Administration, it gives another error:

[COMException (0x80004005): Cannot complete this action.

Please try again.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.OpenWebInternal(String bstrUrl, ....

So it looks like that it's trying to open the dir that contains the asmx as a web.

My questions would be:

1. Why does it work when it's top level? (even with the rule to block asmx on central administration enabled)
2. Is there a way to make it work with this flag on central administration?
3. Is there a way to make it work without the flag on CA?

Any kind of help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to drop your ASMX in the ISAPI folder of your SharePoint environment...  You should access it from any SharePoint structure, because it's a virtual directory.  That way, you would access it by : http://server/_vti_bin/ws.asmx ans even from http://server/subsite/_vti_bin/ws.asmx.

Comment: That's right - I believe you will need to modify the .disco and .wsdl files to support service virtualization. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583131(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: is this strictly necessary? or just the asmx and the assembly in GAC will work ok?

Comment: It is not necessary, but highly recommended, I would say... Because those pages are quite special, you could have that kind of problems... Is there a specific reason to it that way ?

Comment: as it involves a server-wide change, the less files the better (IT team of the client is very restrict regarding deploy packages). Thanks, I'll run some tests on monday.